# My installed Ubuntu 10.10 system is broken. Can I install 12.04 over it using the Wubi installer?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 10.10, windows, wubi

I installed Maverick Meerkat when it came out alongside Windows 7, via the traditional installer (*not Wubi*). So everytime I restart/booted up my computer, I'd get a purple OS selection screen, to select between the Ubuntu version or Windows 7. However, after I updated it to Natty Narwhal, the GUI basically stopped working and I couldn't get it to work. Now when I log in I have 2 linux options (one with a recovery mode), one Windows 7 option, two options that say Wintestx86, and one that opens up previous versions of ubuntu (as a a separate folder).

My quesiton is, I really want to try ubuntu, so if I install the latest version, 12.04, using the WUBI installed, can I just overwrite the previously installed Ubuntu versions? I don't want to overwrite the windows partition/affect my windows data in any way possible. 
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the WUBI installer installs Ubuntu itself inside your Windows partition.

Use the liveCD you used to install Ubuntu in the first place to remove your Ubuntu partitions. Then resize your Windows partition so it fills your entire drive.
(Using Gparted, it's in the System menu)

Then, boot from the Windows install CD, and select repair bootloader (or something like that).

You can then install the latest Ubuntu using WUBI or a liveCD/liveUSB.

Comment: Here's [an alternate procedure you can use to remove](http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/22949) the Maverick system (if you prefer).